# Passing a linked list without memory leak in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, linked-list

In many occasions, we need to modify a linked list drastically so we will sometimes create another linked list and pass it to the old one. For example,

```
struct node {       //let's say we have a linked list storing integers
    int data;
    node* next;
};
```

and suppose we already have a linked list storing integers 1,2,3.

```
node* head; //suppose we already store 1,2,3 in this linked list
node* new_head ; //suppose we make a temporary linked list storing 4,5,6,7
head = new_head; //modifying the original linked list
```

**My Question**
If I delete head (the old linked list) before the assignment then the whole program will crash.
Conversely, if I do not delete it, then there will be a memory leak.
Therefore, I am looking for a way to modify the linked list without memory leak.

**My attempt**
I tried to make a helper function similar to strcpy to do my work.

```
void passing_node(node*& head1, node* head2){   //copy head2 and paste to head1 
    node* ptr1 = head1;
    for (node* ptr2 = head; ptr2 != nullptr; ptr2 = ptr2->next)
    {
        if (ptr1 == nullptr){
        ptr1 = new node;
        }
        ptr1->data = ptr2->data;
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
}
// note that we assume that the linked list head2 is always longer than head1.
```

However, I still got a crash in the program and I cannot think of any other way to modify this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The best way to deal with linked lists in C++ is to never use them. The next best way is to use the standard library.  No one has time to reinvent the wheel. Everything has already been written before us.

Comment: There is a solution but it comes with a tradeoff. Lets assume you delete head and assign head to next node, there is memory leak as you said. One solution might be before delete head, you can assign child notes to the parent node and slide whole linked list to the head. But as you can predict, in long linked lists, this operation is very costly.

Comment: Why does `head = new_head` crash if you already deleted `head`? I mean, you'll still leak the `2,3` nodes, but deallocating the `1` node should not break the code shown.

Comment: Perhaps the head is part of an array in my program, so deleting it will cause a crash. This is why I would like to find a way without deleting and redirecting the original pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest preallocating the linked list so it's easy to delete every node in one call. The nodes would then just reference somewhere inside this preallocated memory. For example:

```
struct Node
{
    int   value;
    Node* next;
};


struct LinkedList
{
    Node* elements;
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    Node* free_list;

    LinkedList(size_t size)
    {
        first     = nullptr;
        last      = nullptr;
        elements  = new Node[size]{0};
        free_list = elements;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
            free_list[i].next = &free_list[i+1];
        free_list[count-1].next = nullptr;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        delete[] elements;
    }

    void Add(int value)
    {
        if (free_list == nullptr)
            // Reallocate or raise error.

        // Take node from free_list and update free_list to
        // point to the next node in its list.

        // Update last node to the new node.

        // Update the first node if it's the first to be added.
    }

    void Free(Node* node)
    {
         // Search for the node and update the previous and
         // next's pointers.

         // Update first or last if the node is either of them.

         // Add the node to the last place in the free_list
    }
};
```

From here you'll have many strategies to add or remove nodes. As long as you make sure to only add nodes to the allocated `elements` array, you'll never have any memory leak. Before adding, you must check if the array have the capacity to add one more node. If it doesn't, you either have to raise an error, or reallocate a new the LinkedList, copy over all values, and delete the old one.

It becomes a bit more complicated when the array becomes fragmented. You can use a 'free list' to keep track of the deleted nodes. Basically, a LinkedList of all nodes that are deleted.

Just take notice that my code is incomplete. The basic approach is to create an allocator of some sort from which you can allocate a bulk, use segments of it, and then delete in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to avoid memory leak is to avoid raw owning pointers.

You might use `std::unique_ptr` (or rewrite your own version):

```
struct node {
    int data = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};
```

You can move nodes.

You can no longer copy nodes (with possible double free issue).

so deep_copy might look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> deep_copy(const Node* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr) return nullptr;
    auto res = std::make_unique<Node>();
    res->data = node->data;
    res->next = deep_copy(node->next.get());
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a nice solution. But I am not allowed to change the struct node in my program :(

Comment: `node` needs a custom destructor now though. Because otherwise the destructor is reursive which can easily overflow the stack in case of large list.

Comment: Without `unique_ptr`, `deep_copy` is mostly the same. You would need a `void delete_node(Node*& node) { if (node) {  delete_node(node->next); delete node; node = nullptr; } }`.

Comment: @eerorika: For small projects, when we have to rewrite list ourselves, I don't think it is an issue; for real projects, we use real containers such as  `std::vector` :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Even a small project may need to store a million elements sometimes.